# Django 1.7 dumpdata on Windows scrambles unicode characters

Tags: python, django, windows, powershell, python-unicode

I use `manage.py dumpdata --format xml --some-more-parameters` to export a full dump of the database to xml. The database is MS sql server and I'm using pyodbc as the driver. The dumpdata command is run using PowerShell and since Django 1.7 does not support a `--output` argument for the `dumpdata` command I redirect the output into a file using PowerShell.

Unfortunately the database contains unicode characters (e.g. country \xd6sterreich) and these characters are scrambled int the export file.

Here's what didn't work:

`./manage.py dumpdata --format xml > export.xml`

`./manage.py dumpdata --format xml | out-file -encoding utf8 export.xml`

`./manage.py dumpdata -format xml | out-file -encoding ANY_OTHER_SUPPORTED_ENCODING export.xml`

None of these commands work. Umlauts and accents are scrambled and additionally the `> export.xml` method adds an invalid `BOM` to the file which will result in `./manage.py loaddata export.xml` aborting with an UnicodeDecode error message when I try to import this on another host.

Any suggestions on how I could export the data and preserve the special characters? The same problem exists when using the json or yaml serializers.

Comment: This question is answered!. See below. Seems I need to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer...

Comment: I wonder if proper `start-process python.exe -passthru -argumentlist $params` would allow your Powershell script access to unaltered stdout. If anything, you might be able to get stdout as string with `-redirectstandardoutput`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that out next time I have access to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to work around this problem using my own export script. The script below will dump the data and store it in a utf-8 encoded xml file called `export_CURRENT-DATE-TIME.xml`. `call_command()` calls the `dumpdata` command in Django. The script below should be equivalent to using dumpdata with the following arguments:

`./manage.py dumpdata --natural --natural-foreign --natural-primary --format xml --indent 2`

```
import sys
import codecs
import os
import django
from django.core.management import call_command
from StringIO import StringIO
from datetime import datetime

# setup access to django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "PROJECT_NAME.settings")
django.setup()

# the actual export command
def do_work():
  #print(u"\xd6sterreich")
  call_command('dumpdata', use_natural_keys=True, use_natural_foreign_keys=True, use_natural_primary_keys=True, format='xml', indent=2)

# nasty hack to workaround encoding issues on windows
_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = StringIO()
do_work()

value = sys.stdout.getvalue().decode('utf-8')
sys.stdout = _stdout

with codecs.open('export_{}.xml'.format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")), 'w', 'utf-8-sig') as f:
  f.write(value)

print("export completed")
```